# Replace blanks with nearest non-blank cell in Google Sheets query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Given the following table:

```
Col1   Col2
1      Lorem
       Ipsum
2      Dolor
3      Sit
       Amet
       Consecutor
```

I am trying to query this to another sheet with the values of `Col1` replaced with the previous non-blank cell in the column, e.g. the result would look like this:

```
Col1   Col2
1      Lorem
1      Ipsum
2      Dolor
3      Sit
3      Amet
3      Consecutor
```

I've tried so many things: `query()` `ArrayFormula()`  `filter()` `row()` `index()` `lookup()`. I'm at my wit's end. Can anyone help with formula or otherwise technique for doing this? I can't do anything in the target sheet because the source sheet can be updated at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this simple formula in Col3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), 
 {IF(A:A<>"", ROW(A:A)), A:A}, 2), B:B}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col2 !=''"))
```